# Postfix check_sender_access unused

Tags: postfix

I am running Postfix 3.3.0 on a host which acts as a mail server for a development environment. It therefore captures all mail as if it were local. But in order to make accessing the mails it has received a bit easier, it splits these into mailboxes based on the FROM address.

Formerly I was using:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

which worked exactly as intended. However this only applies the match to the domain part of the FROM address. My users want to split mail up based on the whole of the FROM address, so I changed the line above to:

```
check_sender_access = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

However when I reload this configuration, I get this reported in the logs:

```
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: check_sender_access=hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

(and the redirection doesn't work).

The man pages which go along with the version of Postfix include a description of check_sender_access - it appears to be supported.

What am I doing wrong?

The main.cf contains....

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
myorigin = devmail.example.com

check_sender_access = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual.alias.txt
mydestination = pcre:/etc/postfix/localdeliverydomains.txt
luser_relay = default

relayhost =
mynetworks = 10.1.0.0/16 127.0.0.0/8 
inet_interfaces = all
recipient_delimiter = +

smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
myhostname = devmail.example.com
mailbox_size_limit = 1280000000

# tested with compatibility_level unser, =2 and =3
compatibility_level = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the correct syntax is:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```